403 Requests from referer <empty> are blocked. [reason: \"API_KEY_HTTP_REFERRER_BLOCKED\

"error": "403 Requests from referer  are blocked. [reason:
"API_KEY_HTTP_REFERRER_BLOCKED"\ndomain:
"googleapis.com"\nmetadata {\n  key: "service"\n  value:
"generativelanguage.googleapis.com"\n}\nmetadata {\n  key:
"consumer"\n  value: "projects/883817471146"\n}\n]"

I am trying to hit API but this error appear furthermore 158.38.176.102 is my server ip where my python project host.
This is Code.
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_restful import reqparse
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from PIL import Image
import google.generativeai as genai
import io

genai.configure(api_key="Example")

app = Flask(__name__)

def get_gemini_response(category, title, description, image):
model = genai.GenerativeModel('gemini-1.5-flash')
# Combining category, title, and description into a prompt
input_text = f"Category: {category}\nTitle: 
 {title}\nDescription: {description}"

if input_text:
    response = model.generate_content([fUser: {input_text}', image])
else:
    response = model.generate_content(image)
return response.text
enter code here
@app.route('/check-category-post', methods=['POST'])
def evaluate_image():
try:
    # Extract form data and file
    category = request.form.get('category')
    title = request.form.get('title')
    description = request.form.get('description')
    file = request.files.get('image')

    print("Category:", category)
    print("Title:", title)
    print("Description:", description)
    print("File:", file) 

    if not category or not title or not description or not file:
        return jsonify({"error": "Category, title, description, 
    and image file are required"}), 400

    # Open the image
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(file.read()))

    # Pass the category, title, description, and image to the 
    Gemini model
    response_text = get_gemini_response(category, title, 
    description, image)

    return jsonify({"response": response_text}), 200

except Exception as e:
    print("Error:", str(e))  # Log the error for debugging
    return jsonify({"error": str(e)}), 500

@app.route('/check-category-post', methods=['POST'])

def check_category_post():
# Log headers and raw data for debugging
print("Headers:", request.headers)
print("Raw Data:", request.data)

# Set up reqparse
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('cpf', type=str, required=True, 
location='args')  # Expecting args
args = parser.parse_args()

return jsonify({"message": "Success", "data": args}), 200

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)


want to solve this problem.

Could you provide us your code ? I have deduced you were trying to use Gemini API if I'm correct https://ai.google.dev/api?lang=python

please edit your question and include [example]  are you sure that key was created in AI studio?

Question Updated.

I resolved the issue by adding my server's IP address to the allowed IPs for my Google API key. However, it only started working 24 hours after making the change.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
